# How to create this kind of card layout in css

Tags: css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moO6l.png]

I am looking to create this kind of card layout how to get that blue on both side of the card.
The only thing i would like to know is how to get that blue on left and right side of the card.

```css
.card {
height: 300px;
width: 400px;
background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you only targeting on the rounded edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap The card with container with two childern.

1- Then add `overlay` div with absolute positioning (this will be the blue side)

2- The card (white div)

N.P: I've added `flex` to body just to center the card, no need for it.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
}

.card-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(#4180B9, #42BDBB);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="card">
  </div>
```